# Asnycio - RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task Unclosed client session

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to get some response from an api for which I am using a wrapper.

I looked for some more error but they did not solve my problem. I dont know much about await a function or coroutines. I turned the is_asnyc off, it worked but I need that option. So I cant turn it off.

```py
import clashroyale, asyncio
token = "my token"
cr = clashroyale.official_api.Client(token=token, is_async=True)

async def top():
    p = await cr.get_top_players()
    return p

topplayers = asyncio.run(top())
```

**I excepted it to just get the information from the api but an error arises**-

```
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001774361A3C8>
```

Comment: This is not an error, just a warning, that the Client didn't close the connection. But where is the error you mentioned in the title?

Comment: OH I didnt see that he error line did not get displayed

Comment: And can u tell me why the warning comes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try moving the initialization of the client inside the async method. It probably tries to use an async timeout context manager, and since you are not inside a task it fails

Comment: Thanks it worked but can you tell how do I remove these warnings- `Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000022BA34C7780>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000022BA37408E8>, 35757.515)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000022BA34C77F0>`

Comment: Also I have to define that client initialisation in every function. Can you tell any other way I would not have to define it everytime.

Comment: I would define it one time in the main method, then send it. Additionally, you can close the session at the end. Something like this https://gist.github.com/Ronserruya/d0daea9e9b436e5821bb9cbbc2b8f7cd

Comment: Ok thanks But in that you defined it in main I will be using classes and I found the way to do that.